# XPath - querying text strings that don't exactly match

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using XPath's contain function to query the "description" element of the XML file below. When using "brand new" to query (as shown in the xpath expression code below), it retrieves the XML data. However if "low price brand new" is used, nothing is retrieved. The obvious conclusion is that the contain function will only retrieve exact matching text strings and will NOT work if the the words are separated from each other as in the description element below.

Does XPath have a function or method that would retrieve the XML data below when querying the description element with the string "low price brand new"? Thanks!

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product[contains(description, "brand new")]');  
foreach($query as $Products) {
echo $Products->name . " ";
echo $Products->description . "<br>";
}

<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
<description>low price, 17 inch screen, brand new </description>
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: Nope, not with XPath 1.0 functions, but you can of course use 2 `contains()` queries. Also, you might want to use `normalize-whitespace()`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be using

```
/products/product[contains(description, "brand new") and contains(description, "low price")]
```

Of course, this is very specific to your example.

You could generalize a little by splitting your string. In Xpath 1.0:

> /products/product[contains(description, "brand") and contains(description, "new") and contains(description, "low") and contains(description, "price")]

In Xpath 2.0:

> /products/product[contains(description, tokenize("low price brand new", "\s+"))]